# undefined method `file' for #<Parse::Client:0x000000065b5738>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, parse-platform

I am using https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#files ruby gem for parse cloud platform.
I am trying to upload images on parse with their documented method as below:

```
photo = client.file({
  :body => IO.read("test/parsers.jpg"),
  :local_filename => "parsers.jpg",
  :content_type => "image/jpeg"
})
```

When I run this in console, getting the error below.

**undefined method `file' for #**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize your client first:

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

client = Parse.create :application_id => '<your_app_id>',
                      :api_key        => '<your_api_key>',
                      :quiet          => true | false
```

https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#client-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting an error while trying to call a `file` method on whatever is stored in your `client` variable, it appears that client isn't holding what you expect it to hold — i.e. it doesn't seem to actually hold an object that responds to the `:file` message.

While it's not clear from your code snippet what the context of your code is, my guess is that you never set it up to hold a client object.

Check out the [section towards the top of that gem's README](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client#client-initialization) for information about initializing the client — that should help you get on your way. Once you've setup your client and stored it in a the `client` variable, you'll be able to call all the methods that the Gem creates for instances of the `Client` class.